# What is role of parameter learning rate, lr, and momentum constant, mc in Neural Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, statistics, gradient-descent

can anyone describes the more simplified mathematical formulation of learning rate, lr, and momentum constant, mc in Neural Networks while training the data?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what your confusion is?  What do you mean by "the more simplified mathematical formulation"?  What formulation do you already know?  What research have you done, and what resources have you already looked at?  What makes you think there is a more simplified formulation?

Comment: I am deep learning researcher.I have trained my model and classified my dataset.Now i needs it mathematical interpretation.i mean general derivations of training and testing data in NN and SVMS